# How to use Promise all() to execute both function at the same time?

Tags: javascript, ajax, es6-promise

I have two ajax functions :  should run together.

```
        getCountryList: function () {
            var self = this;
            App.elementService.getCountries().then(function (countriesList) {
                self.countryData = countriesList;
            });
        },

        getData: function () {
            var self = this;
            this.getElementTypeSchema(App.variable.SelectedCustomerName).then(function (elementTypeValues) {
                self.elementTypeData = elementTypeValues;
                self.render(elementTypeValues);
            });
        },
```

`getCountryList()` should execute `before self.render(elementTypeValues) or at the same time` while `getData()` execute. After searching about promise , I found `Promise.all()` could work here. but I don't know how to do this.

or any other option would be ok for me?
Thank you

Comment: Those functions don't return a promise. Just call them one after the other, they'll execute concurrently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Promise.all` takes an array of promises, which returns a `Promise` in itself which has an array of results in the resolved function.

```
getAllData: function() {
  var self = this;
  Promise.all([
    App.elementService.getCountries(),
    self.getElementTypeSchema(App.variable.SelectedCustomerName)
  ]).then(function(res) {
    self.countryData = res[0];
    self.elementTypeData = res[1];
    self.render(res[1]);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute one after the other to execute concurrently or you can create Promises to use Promise.all([]).

But I think that you don't need that for what you want to do.

This is an example using Promises, you can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

The method parameter `resolve` is used to tell the Promise that you already finished the execution.

```js
var fun1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  console.log('fun1');
  resolve();
});

var fun2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  console.log('fun2');
  resolve();
});


Promise.all([fun1, fun2])
  .then(function() {
    console.log('success!');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Promise.all` in order to handle multiple promises to run parallelly.

```js
const promise1 = () => {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout( () => {
      resolve('promise1')
    }, 1000)
  })
}

const promise2 = () => {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout( () => {
      resolve('promise2')
    }, 1000)
  })
}

const promise3 = () => {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout( () => {
      resolve('promise3')
    }, 1000)
  })
}

Promise.all([promise1(), promise2(), promise3()])
.then( (res) => {
  console.log('Res: ', res);
})
.catch( err => {
  console.log('Error: ', err);
})
```